# use beamer auctex'hooks with class file derived from beamer

Tags: beamer, emacs, auctex, documentclass-writing

I have written my own beamer-derived .cls file to avoid copying and pasting my usual preamble.
A MWE would be

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]%
\ProvidesClass{own_beamer}[2018/06/19 my own slides 2018]
\LoadClass{beamer}
\RequirePackage{booktabs}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
```

It works well. I use Emacs for my LaTeX writing and like all the hints it can provide. For instance, when I create a new frame in a beamer class document, Emacs asks for the frame title. In the same manner, when I want to include a picture, Emacs asks me for the picture file (and eventually the options I want to add).

The thing is that when I use my own-beamer document class, I don't get any of these hints. I think it's because AucTeX does not recognize it's derived from beamer. When I use the `C-c C-n` Emacs command, it does not help.

Any help to fix this?

Comment: you could certainly do this but a simpler way might be to use beamer class and then put the requirepackage and other customisations in a custom beamer theme file, so that auctex sees it as beamer

Comment: You don't need `\RequirePackage{graphicx}` if you load beamer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Using `M-x TeX-auto-generate` in the simplest way

The simplest way is, I think:

1. Inside Emacs, in a buffer using AUCTeX, do `C-h v TeX-auto-private` and create the directory corresponding to the variable's value (typically, `/home/myusername/.emacs.d/auctex/auto`).
2. Run `M-x TeX-auto-generate`. At the first prompt, give a directory containing your personal class and style files you would like AUCTeX to know about. For instance, if your `own_beamer.cls` lives in `/home/myusername/texmf/tex/latex/MyName`, then you could give this directory, but choosing `/home/myusername/texmf/tex` would also work because the search is recursive (of course, it would probably find more files). At the second prompt, accept the default (typically, `~/.emacs.d/auctex/auto`).

   This is going to create `/home/myusername/.emacs.d/auctex/auto/own_beamer.el`, and similar `.el` files for your other personal `.sty`, `.cls`, etc. files found under the directory you indicated at the first prompt.
3. Visit an AUCTeX-using buffer having `\documentclass{own_beamer}` and type `C-c C-n` inside that buffer (or just restart Emacs).

## Keeping a handcrafted AUCTeX helper in `TeX-style-private`

A variation on the previous method consists in copying the aforementioned `own_beamer.el` file to `/home/myusername/.emacs.d/auctex/style/own_beamer.el` and modifying it by hand, if you want to adjust details (`own_beamer.el` can also be obtained without running `TeX-auto-generate`, by visiting `own_beamer.cls` and looking in subdirectory `auto` relative to `own_beamer.cls`, or the directory set up with `TeX-auto-local`). This way, AUCTeX will find the helper info just as in the previous section (was in `/home/myusername/.emacs.d/auctex/auto/own_beamer.el`; note the `auto` path component instead of `style`), but as far as I understand it, will not modify it. In particular, `M-x TeX-auto-generate` should never overwrite your changes in directory `/home/myusername/.emacs.d/auctex/style`.

Sample contents for `/home/myusername/.emacs.d/auctex/style/own_beamer.el`:

```el
  (TeX-add-style-hook
   "own_beamer"
   (lambda ()
     (TeX-run-style-hooks
      "latex2e"
      "beamer"
      "booktabs"
      "graphicx")
     LaTeX-dialect))
```

This was mostly auto-generated when visiting or saving `own_beamer.cls`. Most notably, I replaced the `:latex` dialect with variable `LaTeX-dialect` because this is what the [AUCTeX documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Simple-Style.html#Simple-Style) suggests:

> In case of adding a style hook for LaTeX, when calling function
>   `TeX-add-style-hook` it is thought more futureproof for argument
>   dialect-expr to pass constant `LaTeX-dialect` currently defined to
>   `:latex`, rather than passing `:latex` directly.

## Loading the AUCTeX helper info from `.emacs.el` and friends

A third way, similar to the previous one but maybe a bit less optimized in terms of load times (code executed every time you enter `LaTeX-mode`), consists in loading the AUCTeX helper info (Emacs Lisp code) from your Emacs initialization file(s) as shown below. Then restart Emacs and visit your file that has `\documentclass{own_beamer}`.

Sample code for `~/.emacs.d/init.el`, `~/.emacs.el`, `~/.emacs` or a file of your own loaded by any of these:

```el
(require 'tex-site)

(defun my-LaTeX-add-own-beamer-helper-info ()
  (TeX-add-style-hook
   "own_beamer"
   (lambda ()
     (TeX-run-style-hooks
      "latex2e"
      "beamer"
      "booktabs"
      "graphicx")
     LaTeX-dialect)))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'my-LaTeX-add-own-beamer-helper-info)
```

Comment: Good to know, I have expanded the answer. :)